# Can't get Spring Retry to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I've been attempting to make my Spring application use Spring Retry for the past few days with no luck so far. I have an XML based config so I've tried adding

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean class="org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration" />
```

along with adding the needed dependencies and setting the function I'm using `@Retryable`, this didn't work.

I've also added a component-scan in my XML for a newly created config file, to which I've added `@Configuration` and `@EnableRetry`. I've tried this both with an empty config file and one with a ReturnPolicy set up in it, tried both of these setups with and without Aspects instead of using `@Retryable`. Neither options worked.

I'm running out of sources and ideas to explore, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the spring version?

Comment: It's 4.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: Show the code that is using `@Retryable` and how you are invoking this.

Comment: The retried code is in a @Service java:
`@Retryable public void postData(final Variable var) throws RestClientException {
initConnections();
final HttpEntity<Variable> request = buildRequest(var);
restTemplate.exchange(URL,HttpMethod.POST, request, APIResponse.class);
}`
Called from a @Controller
`try{
  myService.postData(variable)
}
catch(RestClientException e){
 //code
}
`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are setting and calling it correctly. The [@Retryable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html) annotation on the method to be discovered needs to be called correctly from an initialised spring context. Are you doing that( method invoked from a bean from the spring context) or called by other means - outside context?

Alternatively JUnit is best friend - try [SpringJunit4ClassRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html)

You should restructure your test class at least to something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyConfig.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Configuration
    @EnableRetry
    @Import(myService.class)
    public static class MyConfig {}
```

Couple of reference pages are [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Comment: I'm calling the method from a Controller annotated class in the same context, the retryable function is in a Service class. They're both in the same project and are scanned in my applicationContext.xml